# Static object reference inside an object gets copied?

Tags: java, memory, reference, static

I was wondering if I create a static object and pass it as a value to another object, if that object copies the object or I just have a reference...

I want to create a single image and share it among other objects of the same class, like this:

In **Player.class**:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage();

Animation animation1 = new Animation(image, 1, 2);
Animation animation2 = new Animation(image, 3, 6);
Animation animation3 = new Animation(image, 5, 10);
```

in **Animation.class**:

```
private BufferedImage img;

public Animation(BufferedImage image, int frame, int maxframes){
this.img = image;
}
```

I want each animation to be individual, but use the same image, but I was wondering if inside they get copied (the image, so i have 2 in memory) or they are just gettin referenced.

I dont want to create 100 animations with 100 images, but just 1 image and 100 animations.

***NOTE: The classes are just to make my point. They are not real.***

Comment: There are not `static` objects. There are static variables which reference objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is very similar to `java is passed by reference or value`, to clarify this, here is my [githubpage](http://rugal.github.io/programming/2013/12/26/java-is-pass-by-reference-and-pointer-eliminated/)

Actually Java is passed by value, but what created while passing value into method parameter is a `pointer` in `C/C++` rather than `reference` in `C++` conception, which means you they only share the same memory address(in java format), but are not an alias of the parameter that passed in.

Hence with promise, all these three image are one object of outer `image`, any one making any change on it will have influence on others.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, parameters are passed by value. That means that the value of the reference is passed to a method.

If you pass a static variable, the same reference is passed to each animation. That means that if you modify the image inside the animation, you'll be modifying the same one static copy of the image.

You need to create a deep copy of the image if you want to modify it separately.